# Data for car parts and sensors

Tags: obd-ii, sensor, parts, dtc

If a fault code appears in the OBD scanner, how tough is it to map the fault to the part of the car that is causing the problem? Is there any website (or api or mobile app) that has this mapping so that with each fault code I know which part(s) needs to be repaired/replaced?
Also where can I find the **cost of car parts or sensors (manufacturer specific, and still better if that is car model specific)** that need to be changed when a fault code appears?

Comment: Get the factory service manual. They typically detail all DTCs and related troubleshooting procedures.

Comment: Yes, manuals do have the troubleshooting procedures, but I am also interested in a catalogue containing the prices of the parts/sensors that needs to be replaced/repaired

Comment: There is no 1:1 mapping between DTCs and parts. Thus, the diagnostic procedures in the manuals, which use the DTCs - or combinations thereof - as a starting point.

Comment: Questions regarding prices or shopping assistance are off topic for this site, as they are extremely dependent on location, and tend to become obsolete quickly. Internet forums specific to your vehicle would be the best place to start.